# How to localize dates in python?

Tags: datetime, python-2.7, localization, google-drive-api

I'm computing difference between two dates. One date came from Google Drive's *createdDate*, other date is from datetime.now(). I'm thinking I should get the localized value of *createdDate* so that the computed difference is accurate.

Please help or guide me what should I do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates returned in Google Drive's queries are in [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) format. Default timezone is UTC.

If you are using Python, [feed.date.rfc3339](http://home.blarg.net/%7Esteveha/pyfeed.html) is a RFC 3339 date parser and you might want to use this to interact with Python's native datetime library.